# react-moment where to set moment.locale

Tags: reactjs, localization, momentjs

After reading react-datepicker [doc's](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker) I have tried changing my date picker language as the doc's instructions:

> Globally by calling moment.locale(lang) Picker-specific by providing
>   the locale prop

My question is where to write this setting in a react app.

1- app.js (constructor).

2- date-picker component(constructor).

3-somewhere else...

And how to set it as prop, I have tried :

```
<DatePicker locale='gr'
      minDate={this.props.minDate}
        selected={this.state.startDate}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        disabled = {this.props.disabled}
    />;
```

and it is still showing up as English.

BTW - anyone know what is the language string to Hebrew? thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using [this](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/issues/1250) question I was able to figure this so, import langue like:

```
import 'moment/locale/he';
```

And for each new `moment` just set -

```
moment().locale('he')
```

It is not really global(one signal setting) for all uses.

[moment doc](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/loading-into-nodejs/)

Comment: if you do the import 'moment/locale/he' in the root component it would be enough to set the local for all components (I've just tested it)

Comment: Also notice that you can import it dynamically with import(`moment/locale/${navigator.language.toLocaleLowerCase()}`).then();

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct answer **if the goal is to set it globally** would be to put it in `App.js` just after the imports.

```
import moment from 'moment';
// Set moment to FR
moment().locale('fr');
...

function App() {
  return (
...
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need moment.locale(lang) globally then try react context api (for React v16.3 or greater). For Hebrew locale code is `he`, I think.