# Date formatting in React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, datetime, ecmascript-6

I try to format a date time value according to device settings.
Whatever I change on the simulator settings or in xCode scheme, I always get US format with `date.toLocaleDateString()`

So I tried different librairies (moment, react-native-localize, ...) but same, always get US format.

So I tried to set Locale directly with this code :

```
  const date = new Date(Date.UTC(2019, 11, 26, 14, 5, 0))
  const options = {
     dateStyle: 'medium',
     timeStyle: 'short',
  }
  console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options))               // Dec 26, 2019, 3:05 PM
  console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('fr-FR', options))               // Dec 26, 2019, 3:05 PM
  console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', options).format(date))  // Dec 26, 2019, 3:05 PM
  console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('fr-FR', options).format(date))  // Dec 26, 2019, 3:05 PM
```

And I still get same results !

What can I do to display my date in other Locale than 'en-US' ?

I don't want to hardcore the format by myself ("DD/MM/YYY HH:mm"), I want to use a Locale I set or better the device's one.

Thanks for advice

Comment: `toLocaleDateString ` will only work in debug-mode in react-native

Comment: Check out the answer of **Itsik Mauyhas** in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51769039/react-moment-where-to-set-moment-locale ... What u need to make it work with moment...

Answer (score 1):

try this code bellow:

```
import Moment from 'moment';

render(){
    Moment.locale('en');
    var dt = '2016-05-02T00:00:00';
    return(<View> {Moment(dt).format('d MMM')} </View>) //basically you can do all sorts of the formatting and others
}
```

here you have a example to format:

```
moment("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY");
```

You may check the moment.js official docs here https://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: Thanks Matheus, but it's not what I'm searching for. I don't want to force the format as 'd MMM' or whatever, I want it displayed based on the phone language, ie 'dd/mm/yyyy' for French, or 'mm-dd-yyyy' for US for example. Very easy to do in swift, but I'm stuck with React Native.

Comment: Furthermore, the example is ok for English, but not for 'fr' for example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51769039/react-moment-where-to-set-moment-locale?noredirect=1&lq=1 please see this

Comment: Hi try this docs: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-localize

Comment: As I said in my message I already tries react-native-localize, which does not permit to change the Locale or get the device's one. Or please explain. About your previous link about Moment, just explained that it does not work when you change locale, the output result is the same. Try with fr for example you will see, or share working code please, thanks.

Comment: https://reactgo.com/format-date-time-javascript/ see this docs

Comment: try new Date().toLocaleDateString("fr-FR",options);

//output  "12/13/19"

Comment: That's exactly the problem, the output should be "13/12/19" with day in first position, and not "12/13/19". The Locale set is not taken into account, whatever you type you get the same result !